# Error loading psycopg2 module in aws with django

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

I am trying to put my django's webpage to AWS. However, I receive a problem. It says to me that It can't find psycopg2 library.

```
Jul  9 17:09:09 ip-172-31-44-212 web: raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
Jul  9 17:09:09 ip-172-31-44-212 web: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named 'psycopg2'
```

Using pip list I can see what things are instaled in my virtual env. And it's clear that I have installed psycopg2.

```
(eb-virt) PS C:\Users\ANDRES\Desktop\GlobalcodigoTfg\project> pip list
Package                Version
---------------------- ---------
APScheduler            3.7.0
asgiref                3.3.4
astroid                2.5.6
attrs                  20.3.0
Automat                20.2.0
aws-psycopg2           1.2.1
backcall               0.2.0
beautifulsoup4         4.9.3
certifi                2020.12.5
cffi                   1.14.5
chardet                4.0.0
click                  7.1.2
colorama               0.4.4
constantly             15.1.0
cryptography           3.4.6
cssselect              1.1.0
cycler                 0.10.0
decorator              4.4.2
dj-database-url        0.5.0
dj-places              4.0.0
Django                 3.2.3
django-apscheduler     0.5.2
django-decouple        2.1
django-durationwidget  1.0.5
django-extensions      3.1.3
django-location-field  2.1.0
docopt                 0.6.2
future                 0.18.2
geocoder               1.38.1
geographiclib          1.52
geonames               0.1.3
geopy                  2.1.0
googlemaps             4.4.5
graphviz               0.16
gunicorn               20.1.0
humanfriendly          9.1
hyperlink              21.0.0
idna                   2.10
incremental            21.3.0
ipykernel              5.5.5
ipython                7.24.1
ipython-genutils       0.2.0
isort                  5.7.0
itemadapter            0.2.0
itemloaders            1.0.4
jedi                   0.18.0
jmespath               0.10.0
jupyter-client         6.1.12
jupyter-core           4.7.1
kiwisolver             1.3.1
lazy-object-proxy      1.5.2
llvmlite               0.36.0
lxml                   4.6.2
Mako                   1.1.4
MarkupSafe             2.0.1
matplotlib             3.4.2
matplotlib-inline      0.1.2
mccabe                 0.6.1
mysql-connector-python 8.0.24
mysqlclient            2.0.3
networkx               2.5.1
numba                  0.53.1
numpy                  1.20.1
pandas                 1.2.3
parsel                 1.6.0
parso                  0.8.2
pickleshare            0.7.5
Pillow                 8.2.0
pip                    21.1.3
pipreqs                0.4.10
plotly                 4.14.3
prompt-toolkit         3.0.18
Protego                0.1.16
protobuf               3.15.8
proxyscrape            0.3.0
psycopg2               2.8
psycopg2-binary        2.9.1
pyasn1                 0.4.8
pyasn1-modules         0.2.8
pycparser              2.20
PyDispatcher           2.0.5
pydot                  1.4.2
pydotplus              2.0.2
Pygments               2.9.0
pylint                 2.8.2
pyOpenSSL              20.0.1
pyparsing              2.4.7
pyreadline             2.1
python-dateutil        2.8.1
python-decouple        3.4
pytz                   2021.1
pywin32                301
pyzmq                  22.1.0
queuelib               1.5.0
ratelim                0.1.6
requests               2.25.1
retrying               1.3.3
schedule               1.1.0
scipy                  1.6.3
Scrapy                 2.4.1
scrapy-proxy-pool      0.1.9
scrapy-splash          0.7.2
selenium               3.141.0
service-identity       18.1.0
setuptools             57.0.0
Shapely                1.7.1
six                    1.15.0
soupsieve              2.2
spicy                  0.16.0
sqlparse               0.4.1
timezonefinder         5.2.0
toml                   0.10.2
tornado                6.1
trainline              0.1.2
traitlets              5.0.5
Twisted                21.2.0
twisted-iocpsupport    1.0.1
typing-extensions      3.10.0.0
tzlocal                2.1
tzwhere                3.0.3
unicodecsv             0.14.1
urllib3                1.26.4
uuid                   1.30
w3lib                  1.22.0
wcwidth                0.2.5
wheel                  0.36.2
whitenoise             5.2.0
wrapt                  1.12.1
yarg                   0.1.9
zope.interface         5.2.0
```

So, psycopg2 is instaled.

I don't undernstand the problem. I have instaled psycopg2 library

Thank you

Comment: The module list you are showing is on your desktop, but you said you are running the code in AWS. DId you install the modules on the ec2 instance?

Comment: I have installed it in the virtual enviroment. I am following https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html